# Add Images in ImageView of Listview dynamically via Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview which have an imageview. I want to show images (around 600) in listview. For that i want to make such a listview which loads only some images (around 10-15) and when i reach at the bottom of listview it loads further 10-15 images. I have used Custom ArrayAdapter.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Bitmap[] bmp = null;
    Context context;
    Uri[] URIs;
    LayoutInflater layout;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, Uri[] URIs,
            List<String> objects, Bitmap[] bmp) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.bmp = bmp;
        this.context = context;
        this.URIs = URIs;
    }

    class MyViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated constructor
            // stub
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView_row);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return URIs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            layout = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layout.inflate(R.layout.row_hometab_pic, parent, false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(URIs[position]).resize(300, 300)
                .centerInside().into(holder.imageView);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is how you can do it :

1. Create a class by extending the `BaseAdapter`.
2. In the adapter, keep a variable called `itemsToDisplay`.
3. Return this variable in `getCount()`.
4. Return your custom views in `getView()`.
5. Wherever you display the list, add a button at the bottom that says: `Load More Images` or whatever.
6. Clicking the button will increment the `itemsToDisplay` by some value.
7. Call the `notifyDataSetChanged` on your adapter to display more images after the change in `itemsToDisplay`.